# For y While en una sola linea, en python

Tags: python, bucle-for, while

Ejemplo de for y while, son ejercicios de practica, 
pero lo que necesito es como poder hacerlo en una sola línea. 
Gracias.

```
y =0
suma = 0
num = int(input("Ingrese un numero:"))

print()
for x in range(int(num)):
  suma += (x + 1 )
print("Con (FOR) La suma es:", suma)


num = int(input("Ingrese un numero:"))
while y < num:
    y += 1
    suma += y

print("Con (WHILE):", suma)

Esto es lo que hice con For:
print("Con (FOR): ", sum(x for x in range(1, num+1)))
```

Espero alguna ayuda, gracias

Comment: Podrías dar más detalles de lo que deseas hacer no es posible realizar un for y un while en una sola línea ya que son dos bucles distintos.

Answer (score 1):

No sé si pretendías que la suma del `for` y del `while` te den lo mismo, pero tal y como está ahora eso no ocurre.

En primer lugar defines `suma=0`, para luego con el bucle `for` darle un valor. Para el bucle `while` la variable suma ya empieza con ese valor por lo que le añadirá los nuevos cálculos. No tiene porqué ser un error, pero si no es lo que pretendías, deberías definir una variable `suma` para cada bucle (o volverla a poner a cero).

Cuando pones `sum(x for x in range(1, num+1))` puedes omitir el `x for x in` puesto que `range` de devuelve un objeto `range` que puedes sumar directamente:

```
print(sum(range(1, num+1)))
```

O lo que sería lo mismo:

```
print(sum(range(num, 0, -1)))
```

La parte del while, no sé si es esto lo que buscarías:

```
while y < num: y += 1; suma += y; print(suma)
```

Aunque no creo que en este caso aporte nada ponerlo en una línea.